# CORBA IDL Hashmap

Tags: java, corba, idl, iiop

Is there such a way to write CORBA IDL to generate stubs for a Hashmap for storing the following for example?

```
public static final Map<Date, Integer> map = new HashMap<Date, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in control of the server, define it in a remote interface via RMI/IIOP, implement it via `PortableRemoteObject`, and then use `rmic -idl` to generate the IDL, but note that the clients will need an ORB that supports objects-by-value. If the clients are Java just use the RMI/IIOP stubs directly and forget about the IDL altogether.